# How can I start one App from another in android

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android , how can I start one app from inside another in android 
like when I click on one button and I have to start activity of another app

Comment: Post code  of what you have done so far?

Comment: one googles it and finds this as the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Answer (score 1):

You can start another app from you application using intent but **you need to know** its main **activity name or at least that applications package name** , in the following example it uses another apps package name to start

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: @user3652673 please accept the answer if its the one you are looking for,  thank you..